# How to make sure there will be a fixed DB server across multiple deployments in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: microservices, cloud-foundry

I am a newbie with CF microservices and I am trying to deploy a service multiple times. As far as I understood, each time I deploy into a space the application is getting a different database server and schema. Is there a way to tell the Cloud Foundry to use only a fixed DB server all the times across multiple deployments in one environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword for your case is 'Service Instance'

You can create a service instance of database server within the environment specific for your application and bind it via application manifest.

e.g.

```
cf create-service rabbitmq small-plan myapplication-rabbitmq-instance
```

As long as you have a binding to myapplication-rabbitmq-instance in your application manifest it would be preserved/be the same between application deployments within this space.

e.g. in your application manifest:

```
---
...
  services:
   - myapplication-rabbitmq-instance
```

More on https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/

Comment: Thank you Kern..!!

Comment: Just adding a couple things.  It's a common mistake to `cf create-service` multiple times.  As Anatoly says, only do that *once*.  You can then bind the service to your apps as many times as you need.  This mistake often bites people when they're scripting deployments.  You don't really want `cf create-service` in your deployment script.  Instead, what you do want is `cf bind-service` or to list the service instance name in manifest.yml.  Including it in the manifest is the same as `cf bind-service`.